# select the correct LVM volume group as the root device

Tags: linux, grub, lvm

On my disk I have LVM configured as such:

- One Volume Group "vg1", containing

  - One Logical Volume "lv1", containing a LUKS encrypted partition which is the root of a Debian Linux installation
  - One Logical Volume "00" containing another LUKS encrypted partition which is the root of a Qubes OS installation

I want the system to boot into Qubes; in other words, I need to unlock vg1/00 and then mount it as the root device.

The problem is that Grub only asks me to unlock logical volume "lv1". I can't make Grub ask to unlock the "00" logical volume no matter the kernel boot options.

Editing grub's command line at boot I can see `root=/dev/mapper/luks-<UUID>` as well as `rd.lvm.vg=vg1/00` and `rd.lvm.lv=luks.<UUID>`. The UUID matches the correct logical volume.

How can I make sure that grub actually uses the `rd.lvm` boot options?

Comment: Are the kernels and initramfs in the root volumes? If so then it's probably really about grub, and you'll want to check the `cryptomount` commands in grub.cfg; if not then it probably has nothing to do with grub, you'll need to make sure each `linux` line has the appropriate DISTRO-SPECIFIC boot param for the unlocking the right device (e.g. in Arch Linux it's `cryptdevice=`)

Comment: @TomYan I think you're right. Initramfs and kernel aren't in root but in /boot. I looked it up and it seems that Fedora uses different options like `rd_LUKS_UUID`, but yet to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Is qubes based on fedora? At least on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS you need a line in /etc/crypttab:

```
$NAME UUID=$UUID none luks
```

See [crypttab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crypttab).

Replace the `$NAME` with whatever you want and pass this to kernel in `rd.luks.uuid`, and `$UUID` with encrypted device's UUID (see `blkid $DEV`).

You will then need to regenerate init ramdisk (running `dracut -f` should do).

No idea if debian/qubes-os is using the same.